# How to control volume in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

Please can anyone explain me how to change/set volume for audio while it is playing.

Edit from comment: I am using ffmpeg as a decoder and using it with SDL_MIXER. I have added 'volume' filter and set initial volume value. When it is playing i want to set new value of volume. One more thing i am streaming the audio.

Comment: ffmpeg is not a media player, so I don't understand what you are talking about by "while it is playing". Also, you don't mention what you have tried, like for example using your system mixer. Perhaps you mean [ffplay](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffplay.html)?

Comment: Actually i am using ffmpeg as a decoder and using it with SDL_MIXER. I have added 'volume' filter and set initial volume value. When it is playing i want to set new value of volume. One more thing i am streaming the audio. Thanks

Comment: Crossposting is discouraged. Please do not ask the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30188217/how-to-manage-volume-using-ffmpeg) on multiple Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: @gertvdijk `ffmpeg` can actually be used as a media player via the various [output devices](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#Output-Devices) (such as sdl).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Well, I'd say that's unusual at least. The OP should have mentioned that in the original posted question I think. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 4):

To increase the volume with `ffmpeg` use the commad:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -af 'volume=2' output.wav
```

Replace `volume=X` with a suitable number. For example 0.5 will half, 2 will double the volume.

Comment: THE OP asks for changing volume when playing

Comment: Your answer for how to control audio volume while converting

Comment: I think he just wants to increase the volume with ffmpeg, so that it is louder while it is playing. We'll see.

Comment: What does this mean `Please can anyone explain me how to change volume for audio while it is playing.`

Comment: What does this mean `How to control volume in FFMPEG`. FFMPEG is not an audio player.

Comment: For that the OP has -4 score. Since the question has no sense of meaning

Comment: The title is quite clear, not all people speak english well to formulate the question. I think my answer provides the most suitable solution.. Like I said we will see when OP edits his question maybe he can make clear what he wants.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable answer, considering the way the question was asked. One interpretation of "how to change volume for audio while it is playing" is "how to change the volume that the audio will have when the audio plays" (i.e., "when it is playing" could be modifying "the volume..." rather than "to change the volume..."). Of course, the question is somewhat unclear, and hopefully the OP will edit it soon.

Comment: I mean how to set/modify/change/update volume when audio is already playing. I am using FFMPEG as decoder to decode streaming audio. Thanks

Comment: @EliahKagan @Pabi So Why you vote to Close the question with `unclear what you're asking`. How could be unclear with answering!!!

Comment: Because the initial question was unclear, this answer was just one possible thing he could mean